# Import-CSV Powershell v2.0 versus v3.0

Tags: powershell, csv, powershell-2.0, powershell-3.0

I have a script that needs to run both on Powershell v2.0 and v3.0
It imports a csv file and reads a particular value from the first row only. The csv file can have a single row of values or multiple.

```
$file_data = Import-csv -Path $file_name

$col5 = "ColumnName"
```

...

then use `$file_data[0].$col5` in some statement

Here's the difference in `Import-csv`'s behavior between Powershell v2.0 and v3.0

1. On Powershell v2.0, Import-csv returns a non array PSObject object when there is a single row in csv file. So, the above line will throw an error "CannotIndex" `$file_data`.
   But when you have multiple rows in csv, Powershell v2.0 will work fine.
2. On Powershell v3.0, Import-csv always returns an array, so indexing is not a problem.

But if I remove the index and use just $file_data.$col5, Powershell v2.0 will not show any data when the csv has multiple rows.

I am missing out on some thing here. There should be an elagant way to deal with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Why not enclose the `import-csv` cmdlet with `@()` notation that return always an `array`, also in case of a single value and valid in V2 and V3?

```
$file_data = @(Import-csv -Path $file_name)
```

Comment: Interesting, let me test this approach. Thanks C. B.